# delete cookie does not work

Tags: php, session, cookies, setcookie

hello i`m running crazy through a problem that i tried to fetch.

i can not delete a cookie that will be set on index.php like that:

```
$a = 'text';
setcookie('name_of_cookie', $a, time()+60*60*24*365);
```

on page-php i can call that cookie and the content is like $a. i tried to delete that different ways on page.php like that:

```
setcookie('name_of_cookie', FALSE, time()-3600);
```

i also found a version where i only set it to:

```
setcookie('name_of_cookie');
```

what just will set a another cookie with the same name like i saw in the settings of the browser. that new cookie has no content - sure, there is no content declared.

i also tried to set a higher time in the past because of the server location but this doesnt work as well. even trying to set the time to just `1` does not work.

i checked the spelling of the name sveral times, there is no failure that comes from different names.

i would be glad if someone could tell what am i doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Kindly close the browser and do try again as after destroying Cookie it would be removed only after browser re-started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set cookies **be very specific how do you set them**. **Always set domain name** (which can be taken from $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) **and path** (which I usually set to "/"). If you are not consistent something can take "clever" initiative and break your logic. It happens often when you set cookies in JS and try to remove them from PHP (or the other way around). You might have multiple cookies with the same name but different subdomain or path.

For example you set cookies like this:

```
setcookie( 'Foo', 'Bar', time() + 3600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

And you unset them like this:

```
setcookie( 'Foo', '', time() - 999999, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

Missing 2 last arguments will put you in a situation you are at the moment.

Comment: Quick to downvote me and then correct your answer to mine, nice one =o)

Comment: What I correct was removing false with '' which was a valid point. The answer to this problem is making sure OP set/unset cookie with a domain name and path. You can find in his question that he ends up with multiple cookies with the same name. You didn't explain that.

Comment: @ cryptic ツ quick to upvote and accept for me because it is easy to understand whats wrong to my code =o)

Comment: strange about that is, that i thought the cookie will be deleted when reloading the browser. i tested it out on chrome and the the behaviour is like deleting a session?! i didnt restart chrome but could not call the content of the cookie when just reloading?! thanks.

Comment: Chrome can be confusing with cookies. I never trust any cookie inspector there. When investigating cookie issue it's good to have a PHP page which iterates though $_COOKIE. That will give you confidence what you see is true. The other thing is every browser might have different implementation so this is why it's required to be specific. It gets even more confusing when you set cookies from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Delete every cookies as below.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']))
{
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just loop through the superglobal `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: @crypticツ because It contains the raw value of the 'Cookie' header sent by the user agent

Comment: The raw value is irrelevant as you just need the cookie name.

Answer (score 0):

Always set a path while setting cookie otherwise it will not destroy